# Right Notation : Verification with / by / using public-key systems

Tags: phrase-choice

What is the right scientific notation for the following sentence:

Is slower than a verification obtained with / obtained by / using public-key systems?

Answer (score 1):

As someone who uses public-key cryptography, I would say either "verification obtained using public-key systems" or, if I was being less formal, "verification using public-key systems". The other two are not technically incorrect, but they sound clunky.

Answer (score 0):

In your choices using **obtained by using** is the correct form.

> Is slower than a verification **obtained by using** public-key systems

The **by** signifies the verification was obtained through **means using**

Two alternatives to your sentence using **by** and **with** are

> Is slower than a verification **obtained by** public-key systems
>   Is slower than a verification **obtained with** public-key systems

**using** is not necessary since the **usage** of public-key systems is **implied**

Comment: I'm not reading the example sentence as including "obtained by using" as a choice. I only see "obtained by", "obtained with" and "using". Sorry for the double comment, I realized I had an error after the timer to edit comments expired.

Comment: I was reading the **using** was part of the second part of the sentence: "using public key systems". The alternative could be 3 choices: 1) obtained with, 2) obtained by, 3) using.